# Hilbert Nullstellensatz, Eisenbud's proof

Tags: commutative-algebra

I am trying to understand the proof on Eisenbud, *Commutative Algebra with a View Toward Algebraic Geometry*.

The theorem I am trying to prove is:

**Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. If $I \subset k[x_{1},...x_{n}]$ is an ideal, then $I(Z(I))=\mathrm{rad}(I)$**.

"The proof goes like follows: we know that points of $X \subset A^{r}(k)$ are in 1-1 correspondence to maximal ideals in $A(X)$, thus to maximal ideals in  $k[x_{1},...,x_{n}]$ containing $I(X)$. Thus points in $Z(I)$ corresponds to the maximal ideals in $k[x_{1}, ...x_{n}]$ containing $I$. Thus $I(Z(I))$ is the intersection of all maximal ideals containing $I$."

I can't see "Thus points in Z(I) corresponds to the ideals in $k[x_{1}, ...x_{n}]$ containing I. Thus $I(Z(I))$ is the intersection of all maximal ideals containing I." Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You have two sentences in your question. Which part is your question? I think "it" should be "is".

Comment: I can't see both conclusions. ( I have corrected the typo)

Comment: The first conclusion is the previous statement with $X = Z(I)$. (I think you are missing "maximal" here though.) For the second conclusion, one way to do this is showing they are contained in each other using the first sentence of your question.

Comment: Thanks I get it now!

Comment: Great! Good luck.